# conditions on methods rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Relations:

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
end

class Celebrity
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :votes

  def total_downvotes           
    Vote.where('vote_devote = ?', false).count
  end
end
```

this will work, but I need to look for celebrity_id as well that is something like `Vote.where('celebrity_id=?',@celebrities.id, 'vote_devote = ?', false)` in my celebrity model

Can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is smart! Celibrity.votes is automaticall generating the sql query with the celibrity_id associtation. so just call votes method and add where filter. adding the count to just count in sql. easy game.

```
class Celebrity

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :votes

  def total_downvotes      
    votes.where(vote_devote: false).count
  end

end
```